# How to find start and end date of last 4 months including current in php

Tags: php, datetime

I want to get the start and end dates on last 4 months including current month.Please help.

Regards
Jos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do it this way...

```
<?php
// current day to start with
$start = mktime(0,0,0,date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));;

// loop through the current and last four month
for ($i = 0; $i <=4; $i++) {
    // calculate the first day of the month
    $first = mktime(0,0,0,date('m',$start) - $i,1,date('Y',$start));

    // calculate the last day of the month
    $last = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m') -$i + 1, 0, date('Y',$start));

    // now some output...
    echo date('Y-m-d',$first) . " - ".date('Y-m-d',$last). "<br>";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

With PHP 5.2+, you can use [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) to solve this problem:

**Example:**

```
<?php

$date = new DateTime('first day of this month 3 months ago');

// Loop 4 times.
for ( $i = 0; $i < 4; $i++ )
{
  echo 'Start: ' . $date->format('Y-m-d') . PHP_EOL;
  echo 'End: ' . $date->format('Y-m-t') . PHP_EOL;
  
  // Add 1 month.
  $date->add(new DateInterval('P1M'));
}
```

Comment: $currYear  = date("Y");
  $currMonth  = date("m");
  
  $monArr = array();
   
  
  $first = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $currMonth, 1, $currYear))  . ' 00:00:00';
  $last = date('Y-m-t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $currMonth, 1, $currYear))  . ' 00:00:00';

  $monArr['0'] =  $first . '##**##' . $last;


  $prevMoFDate = date('Y-m-d', mktime(0, 0, 0, $currMonth - 1, 1, $currYear))  . ' 00:00:00';
  $prevMoLDate = date('Y-m-t', mktime(0, 0, 0, $currMonth - 1, 1, $currYear))  . ' 00:00:00';

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// start day of current month
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'));

// end day of current month
echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime('-1 second',strtotime('+1 month',strtotime(date('m').'/01/'.date('Y').' 00:00:00'))));
?>
```

you can add or remove months ... and you will get accurate results